# extjs/c# Yes saves to the database

Tags: c#, extjs, ext.net

I have a simple question.

I have a FormView, with a save button. When the button is clicked, it saves to databse.

I've added an EXT message box to confirm if user wants to save the data or not. when he click yes on the messagebox yes button, then it should save the data.

I can't find where to write the yes button logic in the ext.

Here is my code :

```
     <asp:FormView ID="myform" runat="server" DataSourceID="mydatasource" DefaultMode="Edit"  DataKeyNames="Id" >

      <EditItemTemplate>                                              
       <asp:TextBox ID="myText" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ClientIDMode="Static"
        Text='<%#Bind("xx") %>' />                                                  
       <ext:Button ID="btn_Update" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" CausesValidation="false"  CommandName="Update" Text="Speichern" StyleSpec="float: left; margin-left:10px;">                                                                               <DirectEvents>
<Click OnEvent="btnUpdateClick"></Click>
 </DirectEvents>
                                                              </ext:Button> 



    <script type="text/javascript">

    function showResult(btn) 
    {
            Ext.example.msg('Button Click', 'You clicked the {0} button', btn);
        };
        function showResultText(btn, text) 
        {
            Ext.example.msg('Button Click', 'You clicked the {0} button and entered the text "{1}".', btn, text);
        }

        var showResult = function (btn) {
            Ext.Msg.notify("Button Click", "You clicked the " + btn + " button");
        };

        var showResultText = function (btn, text) {
            Ext.Msg.notify("Button Click", "You clicked the " + btn + 'button and entered the text "' + text + '".');
        };


</script>



protected void btnUpdateClick(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
        {
           X.Msg.Confirm("Confirm", "Are you sure you want to save?", new JFunction { Fn = "showResult" }).Show();

        }
```

Comment: Please provide a example/rephrase your question. The message box can't update anything. So it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: the message box has yes and no buttons (do you want to save the data), when user click Yes, it should save the data, I just dunno how I can do it, I will provide the code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that instead of wiring the yes button of the dialog to perform the postback. You should wait for the message box to close and then invoke the postback functionality if the user clicked yes.

For example:

```
Ext.Msg.prompt('SaveChange', 'Would you like to save the changes?:', function(btn, text){
    if (btn == 'yes'){
         __doPostBack('btnSubmit','OnClick');
    }
});
```

Replace btnSubmit with the name of your button.

Although the above solution would be my recommended approach, you could, alternatively, use jquery by doing:

```
$('btnSubmit').trigger('click');
```

Source: http://dev.sencha.com/playpen/docs/output/Ext.MessageBox.html

Comment: Point is, my action is to make the button do a postback action, I cant make this to happen.

Comment: -1 for mixup jquery with extjs. There's no need for using two libraries

Comment: Disagree strongly, jquery is so defacto with asp.net it's practically part of the framework and I have also supplied an standard asp.net method for performing this!

Comment: JQuery is just shipped as default which is perfectly well cause it's the best you will find for that purpose. But this is about Ext.net which is ExtJS driven and not ASP.net MVC. This is neither related to jquery nor is it shipped with it. The other point is, think about application layers... jQuery is just a ...'Hey, you should use this cause we think it fits very well'... Delete the libs and ASP.net MVC  still work the same. And if you choose any other frontend framework like ExtJS, there is no need to keep jQuery. (OK, there are some rare situations, but the are really rare)

Comment: I would agree if I had not also supplied a pure asp.net solution. Your solution does not actually do what the OP requested. You are submitting the request via AJAX, the OP wanted to programmatically click a button when the dialog 'Yes' button was clicked. This isn't the same thing in all scenarios. I feel there is a tactical nature to your objection, rather than a firm concrete techincal one. Never the less, I will update my answer to reflect my preferred approach.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for this: (Can be placed in any Demo-Box of the Sencha API)

**Edit 2**

I have totally overseen that you are using Direct. You should mention such things.
Is there any reason for using DirectEvent? I couldn't test it but how about this *(the wrapping function may be unnecessary, but a normal ExtJS handler get button reference as first argument)*:

```
<form runat="server">
        <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

        <script runat="server">
            [DirectMethod]
            public void SetTimeStamp(string field)
            {
                // do your saving
            }
        </script>
        <ext:TextField ID="TextField" runat="server" FieldLabel="Label"/>
        <ext:Button ID="Button" runat="server" Text="Click Me" Icon="Lightning">
            <Listeners>
                <Click Handler="function() {Ext.Msg.show({title: 'Save?', msg: 'Do you want to save the data?:', buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,fn: function(btn){ if(btn == 'yes') {App.direct.SetTimeStamp(#{TextField}.getValue());}}})}" />
            </Listeners>
        </ext:Button>
</form>
```

**Edit 1** Simply use **[Ext.Ajax.request()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-method-request)**

```
Ext.Msg.show({
        title: 'Save?', 
        msg: 'Do you want to save the data?:', 
        buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
        fn: function(btn, text){
              Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: 'yourUrl',
                method: 'POST',
                params: {
                    // your params
                },
                success: function() {
                    console.log('success');
                },
                failure: function() {
                    console.log('woops');
                }
            });
        }
});
```

*Form example removed*

Comment: Point is, my action is to make the button do a postback action, I cant make this to happen.

Comment: @Mark I made an edit so that now a ajax request is fired after clicking YES

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your support, I found my way through your answers I will put it here maybe it can be useful for someone.

First, button code, need to have Isupload = "true"

```
ext:Button ID="btn_Update" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" CausesValidation="false"
CommandName="Update" Text="Save" StyleSpec="float: left; margin-left: 10px;"
AutoScroll="False">
<DirectEvents>
<Click OnEvent="btnUpdateClick" IsUpload="true" AutoDataBind="true">
</Click>
</DirectEvents>
</ext:Button>
```

in the button event in the aspx :

```
protected void btnUpdateClick(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
{
        MessageBoxButtonConfig buttonYes = new MessageBoxButtonConfig();
        buttonYes.Text = "Yes";
        buttonYes.Handler = "Ext.net.DirectMethods.ClickedYES();";

        MessageBoxButtonConfig buttonNo = new MessageBoxButtonConfig();
        buttonNo.Text = "NO";
        //  buttonNo.Handler = "Ext.net.DirectMethods.ClickedNO();";

        MessageBoxButtonsConfig yesNoButtons = new MessageBoxButtonsConfig();
        yesNoButtons.Yes = buttonYes;
        yesNoButtons.No = buttonNo;

        X.Msg.Confirm("Save Changes", "Would you like to Save?", yesNoButtons).Show();
 }
```

Last the Yes method that will save to database:

```
[DirectMethod]
public void ClickedYES()
{
      Formview.UpdateItem(false);
      Formview.DataBind();
}
```